# Python ElementTree parsing order

Tags: python, printing, elementtree

I have a very novice problem, but i am just getting started and this one is bugging my brain.

This is my XML:

```
<SCHEDULE>
  <PROGRAMMES>
    <PROGRAMME START="00:30:00" END="00:31:00">
      <TITLES>
        <TITLE>Name 1</TITLE>
      </TITLES>
    </PROGRAMME>
    <PROGRAMME START="00:31:00" END="00:32:00">
      <BLOCK>
        <BLOCK_NAME>Block1</BLOCK_NAME>
        <BLOCK_START>00:31:00</BLOCK_START>
      </BLOCK>
      <TITLES>
        <TITLE>Name 2</TITLE>
      </TITLES>
    </PROGRAMME>
    <PROGRAMME START="00:40:00" BILLEDEND="00:45:00">
      <BLOCK>
        <BLOCK_NAME>Block 1</BLOCK_NAME>
        <BLOCK_START>00:31:00</BLOCK_START>
      </BLOCK>
      <TITLES>
        <TITLE>Name 3</TITLE>
      </TITLES>
    </PROGRAMME>
    <PROGRAMME START="00:45:00" END="00:50:00">
      <TITLES>
        <TITLE>Name 4</TITLE>
      </TITLES>
    </PROGRAMME>
  </PROGRAMMES>
</SCHEDULE>
```

This is my Python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

try:
    import textwrap
    textwrap.indent
except AttributeError: 
    def indent(text, amount, ch=' '):
        padding = amount * ch
        return ''.join(padding+line for line in text.splitlines(True))
else:
    def indent(text, amount, ch=' '):
        return textwrap.indent(text, amount * ch)

tree= ET.parse("block.xml")
root=tree.getroot()

for sub in root.findall('.//PROGRAMME'):

    time = sub.get("START")[:5] + " "
    nas = sub.find(".//TITLE").text

    if sub.find(".//BLOCK_NAME") == None:
        block = time + nas
    else:
        block = sub.find(".//BLOCK_NAME").text
        c= indent(time + nas,3)
        block = time + block + "\n" + c

    print(block)
```

Result i get:

```
>>>00:30 Name 1
>>>00:31 Block1
>>>   00:31 Name 2
>>>00:40 Block 1
>>>   00:40 Name 3
>>>00:45 Name 4
```

Now the question:
What am i missing so i would get this result

```
>>>00:30 Name 1
>>>00:31 Block1
>>>   00:31 Name 2
>>>   00:40 Name 3
>>>00:45 Name 4
```

I presume i need to incorporate BLOCK_START somehow but i have no idea how...
Tnx in advance for help

Comment: Ziga, post a proper answer and accept it. That way it is clear to everyone that the problem has been solved. In addition, code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: @mzjn Tnx for info... New on stackoverflow and didn't know everything yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. Just compared START and STARTBLOCK.

```
if sub.find(".//BLOCK_NAME") is None:
    block = time + nas
else:
    if sub.find(".//BLOCK_START").text != sub.get("START"):
        block = indent(time + nas, 4)
    else:
        block = sub.find(".//BLOCK_NAME").text
        c = indent(time + nas, 4)
        block = time + block + "\n" + c
```